# Background Color Not Filling in Entire Row Based off Expression in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, visibility, ssrs-expression

I was hoping I could get some help on this issue. Got a report that displays data for events; of which we have two types: fixed and mobile.

To fill in the row based off what type the event is, I used this expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!OwnerType.Value = "Fixed", "LightSteelBlue", "#FFFFFF")
```

But here is what the result actually look like:

[image: Background Color Not Filling]

The rows with the light blue background color are fixed sites are often not assigned incentives/promotions. And if they aren't, I would still like the entire row to have a background color of light blue.

My issue like in the fact that the incentive columns (Sam's Club, T-Shirts, Wal-Mart, etc) are created dynamically through a column grouping - I have no which values might appear here or how many.

The way I have it configured currently is to put an expression on the cell itself:

[image: Expression]

But it leaves me with my reason for posting, I can't get the entire row to be back filled with this column grouping.

And if I apply the expression `=IIF(Fields!OwnerType.Value = "Fixed", "LightSteelBlue", "#FFFFFF")` to the column grouping the same way I did for the row, it will only change the colors of the individual cells where the incentive is and the header.

Under Group Columns -> Incentives Properties, can I change the visibility to also include the background color fill?

[image: Column Group Properties]

Comment: It means you've got a different background color expression for those three columns/cells, and it's over-riding the expression on the row.

Comment: The Incentive Column is a Grouping that creates as many columns as needed based on the number of Incentives. And the Expression within the Incentive field is: =Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Incentive.Value), Nothing, (Fields!Incentive.Value)).  But I can see in the Properties box, the background color remains the same.  I don't understand why the row would back fill grey for the mobile events, but not back fill for the fixed sites.

Comment: Probably because those columns don't exist at design time.   Try using the same background color expression in the Column grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this expression for the row:

```
=Iif(
Max(
  Iif( Fields!OwnerType.Value = "Fixed", 1, 0 )
  , "Row_Group_Name"
  ) = 0
,"White"
,"LightSteelBlue")
```

Which filled in the entire row.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a switch statement?  To have multiple color options depending on the string value of a field?